# How to make a responsive side bar

Tags: css, html, responsive

I made a side bar in my website but I realized in wasn't responsive and I didn't know how to make it responsive. Can any body tell me how to make a responsive side bar like the one in YouTube.

Comment: it would be better to use frameworks like bootstrap, so that you don't have to make it responsive manually.

Comment: can you add your html and css snipet minimal

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query to your CSS.

[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) on MDN:

> Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen), specific characteristics (such as the width of the browser viewport), or environment (such as ambient light conditions).

It'll depend on how your CSS is structured and what you want to do, but the following will hide your sidebar (using the `.sidebar` class on screen sizes smaller than `768 pixels`).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

That will hide all elements using the `.sidebar` class on screen sizes 768 pixels and less. You can change `max-width` to `min-width` to make it apply to screen sizes above that such as desktops etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want your site to be responsive "easily", you should consider making it with a grid (Bootstrap).

If you want help to make your sidebar responsive, we need you to give the CSS and HTML parts of the sidebar, at the very least, to help you.